# Empty vectors after split

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying write a simple application based on card trick. In some part of that app i have to split alternately a main deck to smaller decks. I wrote a simple loop to do that, but after invoking decks are still empty. I paste  that part of code below. Do you know where i made mistake? Of course if you want check whole program you could do it [here](http://pastebin.com/vVYCVFiQ). That method is invoked by "main" instance of Deck class, smaller deck are parameters of that method.

```
    void split_deck(Deck one, Deck two, Deck three, Deck four, int time)
{
    Deck* on=&one;
    Deck* tw=&two;
    Deck* th=&three;
    Deck* fo=&four;
    on->dck.clear();
    tw->dck.clear();
    th->dck.clear();
    fo->dck.clear();
    int buff;

    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
    {
        buff = dck[i];
        if (i%time == 0) on->dck.push_back(buff);
        if (i%time == 1) tw->dck.push_back(buff);
        if (i%time == 2) th->dck.push_back(buff);
        if (i%time == 3) fo->dck.push_back(buff);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have passed all your decks by value which means these are all copies that go away at the end of the function.  Also, what is with the pointers?

Comment: @NathanOliver My sneaking suspicion is that OP thought "i want to modify the original, i need a pointer to it" but didnt take into account that the copy had already happened (because passed by value as you mentioned). P.S: A reference would have worked even better.

Comment: What is ``dck`` in ``buff = dck[i];``?

Comment: I used pointers because i belived that could solve my problem with empty vectors. In previous version i wrote it in that way: "one.dck.push_back(buff)" but i was worried about number of periods.

Comment: @Jonas Wielicki dck is a vector of instance whitch invoke that method. You could check it in enclosed link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Nathan's comment, you should pass the vectors by reference:

```
 void split_deck(Deck& one, Deck& two, Deck& three, Deck& four, int time)
```

This way, the changes will be preserved and be visible to the caller.
The way you pass the vectors now (by value), you're essentially working on their copies inside the function; the actual vectors outside the function are not changed.

And, yes, please get rid of those pointers (I assume they were there for test anyway) and use the vectors you pass to the function directly.

Comment: You should also suggest he get rid of all the pointers as they are not needed.